# Using Range in VBA and Excel

Tags: vba, excel

The following is valid in VBA

```
Range("K1:K5")
```

Why is the following not valid?

```
Dim nb As Long
Range("K1:K" + nb)
```

I also tried Range("K1:K" & nb) and even tried making nb a `String` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the value of `nb = 0` and the rows in excel start with `1`

Try this

```
Dim nb As Long
Dim Rng As Range

nb = 2
Set Rng = Range("K1:K" & nb)
```

Comment: The issue wasn't the zero value. Your code worked but the following doesn't: Set Rng = Range("K" & nb1 & ":K" & nb2) assuming nb1=10 and nb2=15

Comment: Nothing wrong with `Set Rng = Range("K" & nb1 & ":K" & nb2)` What error are you getting?

Comment: Oddly enough that only happens if nb1=nb2. That would make sense since I suppose a single cell is no longer a range...

Comment: Umm even a single cell is a range. And it shouldn't give you an error even if nb1=bn2 :) Have you defined `Dim Rng As Range` at the top?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the value is for nb.

Try using the Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex) notation where RowIndexand ColumnIndex are integers.

```
Sub RangeExemple()

Dim colIndex, colIndex2, rowIndex, rowIndex2 As Integer

colIndex = 7
colIndex2 = colIndex
rowIndex = 1
rowIndex2 = 5

Range(Cells(rowIndex, colIndex), Cells(rowIndex2, colIndex2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
```

End Sub

What do you want to do actually?

Comment: that's the point ;) he probably didn't know you needed to define a value for nb

Comment: No :-) I wish... I had a value defined, I just didn't show that bit of code. Not defining a value would be a bit naïve...

Comment: Well, the cells approach is very useful when looping, think about it!